# If you reject the null hypothesis at 0.025 level of significance, is it true to say that you may or may not reject it at a significance of 0.01?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

If we just use the normal distribution, we can find that $ \alpha = 0.025 $ covers more area at the tails than $ \alpha = 0.01 $. So it's clear that you may or may not reject at $ \alpha = 0.01 $. But I'm looking for an intuitive explanation here. My reasoning is:

The level of significance, $ \alpha $, is the probability of making a Type - 1 error. At $ \alpha = 0.025 $, you're given more probability of making this error, and so you're given some "leeway" in rejecting it.

If $ \alpha = 0.01 $, you should be more careful than the previous case. So if you reject at $ \alpha = 0.025 $, you may or may not reject at $ \alpha = 0.01 $.

But if you reject at $ \alpha = 0.01 $, you'll always reject at $ \alpha = 0.025 $.

Am I correct in my reasoning?

Comment: Short answer: yes.

Comment: @jbowman Although many readers will understand what you mean, please be aware that the short answer to the question asked in the title is no!

Comment: @whuber - so it is! WorldGov - you should adjust the title to match the content of the question, or vice versa (in the latter case, as whuber points out, my comment is wrong.)

Comment: I've edited the question; and thank you for confirming my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by @jbowman in the comments, the stated explanation is correct.

I'm adding an answer to close this question.